# JSON Header Formatting for Approvals

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I've been trying to add an additional layer of approval to [this already existing code](https://github.com/rdorrani/SharePoint/blob/master/TravelRequest/headerformatting.json). As you can see, it has "Manager Approval" and "HR Approval".

I would like to add "Manager Attachment Approval" and "HR Attachment Approval" with the same format as the already existing approval. The end result would be that the picture below contains all **four** approvals (two extra circles).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JSON you can use to add multiple circles/levels in form header:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralPrimary ms-fontColor-white"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "border": "2px solid #666666",
        "width": "300px",
        "height": "200px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "a",
          "attributes": {
            "href": "='https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + [$Destination.Coordinates.Latitude] + ','+[$Destination.Coordinates.Longitude] + '/'",
            "target": "_blank"
          },
          "style": {
            "height": "100%"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "img",
              "attributes": {
                "src": "='https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/AerialWithLabels/' + [$Destination.Coordinates.Latitude] + ','+[$Destination.Coordinates.Longitude] +'/10?mapSize=300,200&key=YourBingMapsKey&pp='+[$Destination.Coordinates.Latitude]+','+[$Destination.Coordinates.Longitude]+'"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "margin": "5px",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "160px",
        "border": "2px dashed",
        "padding": "10px",
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-direction": "column",
        "align-items": "center"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "Travel Request Process",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontSize-28 ms-fontWeight-bold"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "=[$Destination.DisplayName]",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontSize-16"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Money",
                "class": "ms-fontSize-22 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-white",
                "title": "Issue"
              },
              "style": {
                "flex": "none",
                "padding": "0px",
                "padding-right": "5px",
                "padding-left": "0px",
                "height": "16px"
              }
            },
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "txtContent": "$",
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontSize-16"
              }
            },
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "txtContent": "=[$EstimatedAirfare] +[$EstimatedHotelCost] ",
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontSize-16"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "justify-content": "center",
            "width": "100%"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "140px",
                    "display": "flex",
                    "flex-direction": "column",
                    "align-items": "center",
                    "margin": "20px"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "txtContent": "Manager Approval",
                      "style": {
                        "margin-bottom": "5px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-15"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'CompletedSolid' ,if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by HR' ,'CompletedSolid' , if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending HR Approval' ,'CompletedSolid' ,'CircleShapeSolid')))",
                        "class": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending HR Approval' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by HR' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending Manager Approval' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-yellow' ,if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by Manager' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-red' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary')))))"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "80px",
                    "display": "flex",
                    "flex-direction": "column",
                    "align-items": "center",
                    "margin-top": "50px"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "---------->",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-16"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "120px",
                    "display": "flex",
                    "flex-direction": "column",
                    "align-items": "center",
                    "margin": "20px"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "txtContent": "HR Approval",
                      "style": {
                        "margin-bottom": "5px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-15"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'CompletedSolid' , 'CircleShapeSolid')",
                        "class": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending HR Approval' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-yellow' ,if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by HR' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-red' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary'))"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "80px",
                    "display": "flex",
                    "flex-direction": "column",
                    "align-items": "center",
                    "margin-top": "50px"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "---------->",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-16"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "140px",
                    "display": "flex",
                    "flex-direction": "column",
                    "align-items": "center",
                    "margin": "20px"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "txtContent": "Manager Attachment Approval",
                      "style": {
                        "margin-bottom": "5px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-15"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'CompletedSolid' ,if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by HR' ,'CompletedSolid' , if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending HR Approval' ,'CompletedSolid' ,'CircleShapeSolid')))",
                        "class": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending HR Approval' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by HR' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending Manager Approval' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-yellow' ,if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by Manager' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-red' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary')))))"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "80px",
                    "display": "flex",
                    "flex-direction": "column",
                    "align-items": "center",
                    "margin-top": "50px"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "---------->",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-16"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "width": "120px",
                    "display": "flex",
                    "flex-direction": "column",
                    "align-items": "center",
                    "margin": "20px"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "txtContent": "HR Attachment Approval",
                      "style": {
                        "margin-bottom": "5px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-15"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'CompletedSolid' , 'CircleShapeSolid')",
                        "class": "=if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Approved' ,'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-green',if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Pending HR Approval' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-yellow' ,if([$ApprovalStatus] == 'Rejected by HR' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-red' , 'ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary'))"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can change the `iconName` conditions and styling (width/classes) as per your requirements.

**Documentations**:

1. [SharePoint list-form-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)
2. [JSON formatting-syntax-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)